# Update Mysql records using Same table but Based on same table record

Tags: mysql, update, query, row

I have table in which i want to update records based on it's 'wishlist_id' value.
Sample format of table records.
[image: This is sample records of table before update]

Expected table record after update.

[image: Expected output]

So can you help to update this record using mysql query?

Comment: Does `id` can be used to identify the records where `wishlist` value must be populated? does all records with `name != 'wishlist'` have `wishlist IS NULL`?

Comment: Without any way to link the separate entities to their variables there is no way to update this after the data has been entered. Your options are to add the wishlist ID at the time you do the initial `INSERT` or restructure your tables so that they work in a normalised way and keep the relevant data in separate tables linked by the wishlist_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that all records with `wishlist IS NULL` must be updated with the value taken from the closest previous (while sorting by `id ASC`) record with non-NULL `wishlist` value:

```sql
UPDATE test
SET wishlist = (@tmp := COALESCE(wishlist, @tmp))
WHERE (@tmp := -1)
ORDER BY id ASC
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=db7515500b826867f55c386cadf50a4f)

Comment: .thanks , this query is working, Thanks again!